# Azure SQL Creating Database Scoped Credential

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to create a scoped credential in azure SQL using SSMS.

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL [cred-name] WITH IDENTITY = [db-user], SECRET = 'password'
```

I keep running into the error message stating "Incorrect syntax near 'cred-name'. Expected '='." I'm not sure how my syntax is incorrect as I've done this exact command successfully in the past so I'm not sure what has changed. I thought maybe it was just intellisense that was messing up so I updated my SSMS instance from 17.3 to 17.7 but I still get the same error message.

Does anyone have any idea of what could have changed?

Comment: Are you sure you need the brackets around the Identity property? The docs seem to indicate that should be a string value.

Comment: As a string value I still get the same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Running the exactly T-SQL you posted against **Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   May  4 2018 13:05:56** version leads to the following error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'db-user'.
```

Replacing the identity name brackets for single quotes leads to the error below:

```
Msg 15581, Level 16, State 6, Line 1
Please create a master key in the database or open the master key in the session before performing this operation.
```

Creating the master key with following T-SQL allows me to create the credential **successfully**:

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD='MyPassw0rdIsComplex.'
GO

CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL [cred-name] WITH IDENTITY = 'db-user' , SECRET = 'password'
GO
```

Also, you can check if the scoped credential using the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.database_scoped_credentials WHERE credential_identity='db-user'
```

I'm using SSMS version 17.2, but I'm not sure if this matters since errors would come from the SQL Server engine itself.

Comment: I have a master key in the database already but I didn't know if it had the encryption on it. I alter the master key and added the encryption, which it did successfully, but I'm still getting the same syntax error. I also checked the scoped credentials already in the DB and there are a few blob storage references for logs and auditing.

Comment: Can you post the Azure SQL version you're using by running by running SELECT @@VERSION?

Comment: 12.0.2000.8 Same version as you states above

Comment: Strange. I've run the create database scoped credential command again and it completed. I wonder if some change takes a while to propagate. In any case I'm able to move forward.

Comment: I had this same error and the order of operations does make a difference.  Intellisense always reports the scoped credential as invalid syntax but the command works if issued immediately after creating the master key or opening the master key.  IOW it seems you must know the password to the database master key to mess with credentials.  If it's encrypted under the service master key you may need to open a new session for it to be available.

Comment: This was my problem... it showed a syntax error... but I was able to actually execute it.

Answer (score 2):

The master key needs to be open to enable encryption of the database scoped credential.

So if a master key exists already, you can write the following:

```
OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '<your password>';
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL [<your credential>]
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE', SECRET = '<your SAS secret without the preleading ?>';
CLOSE MASTER KEY; -- only necessary if you need to close the master key context and continue scripting. (it will close with the session/query close)
...
```

if no master key exists, you can write:

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '<your password>';
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL [<your credential>]
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE', SECRET = '<your SAS secret without the preleading ?>';
CLOSE MASTER KEY; -- only necessary if you need to close the master key context. (it will close with the session/query close)
...
```

For some reason intellisense does not understand the syntax - but it will execute as it should regardless.