# Cannot create master key for master database in azure sql

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, ssms

i'm using Azure SQL. In Azure Portal, i was create 1 Azure SQL Server (with username login `user01`) and 2 Azure SQL Database (`ExDatabase1` and `ExDatabase2`) inside it.
In `Microsoft SQL server management studio` tool, i'm login success with user `user01`. i'm using transparent data encryption ([TDE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/transparent-data-encryption-azure-sql?view=azuresqldb-current)) and try create Database Master Key for `master database` with command bellow:

```
USE master;
Go
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION by PASSWORD = 'Strongp@ssw0rd';
Go
```

But, i received error: 
`Msg 15247, Level 16, State 1, Line 3`
`User does not have permission to perform this action.`
So, what is permission for this current user (this is owner database)? and how to do that?. thanks!

Comment: You should be creating the `master key` for any of your own database - ExDatabase1 and ExDatabase2 and you need to have `control` permission too.

Comment: if i'm change `master` by `ExDatabase1` and create master key. it will done!

Comment: Yes it should be provided the user has the required permission

Comment: @Abhishek in Encryption Hierarchy [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/encryption-hierarchy?view=azuresqldb-current) . Database Master Key of ExDatabase1 and ExDatabase2 are protected by the Service Master Key. So, How to craete Database Master Key for master database

Comment: i'm watched in [video on youtube](https://youtu.be/kYeC_3l0f24?t=450) and tried that. But it is `SQL Server`, not `Azure SQL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USE statement is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new connection to connect to a different database on Azure SQL Database.

To create a master key in Azure SQL just run the following statement on the Azure SQL Database context not on the master database.

```
 CREATE MASTER KEY 
 GO
```

For a full example please read [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2015/05/12/recommendations-for-using-cell-level-encryption-in-azure-sql-database/) article.

Another example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50454237/azure-sql-creating-database-scoped-credential).

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD='MyPassw0rdIsComplex.'
GO
```