# Azure SQL - Cannot create encrypted master key

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am trying to create a master key for my database, needed because I follow a tutorial to make cross db queries.

Tutorial: https://www.scarydba.com/2016/03/21/cross-database-queries-in-azure-sql-database/

It is a similar question to [Cannot create master key for master database in azure sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50459793/cannot-create-master-key-for-master-database-in-azure-sql), but I get the message:

> Msg 15578, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 There is already a master key in
>   the database. Please drop it before performing this statement.

...when I am trying to create a master key which is encrypted. What do I do wrong and is there another option to make cross db calls with Azure?

I execute the following:

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD='SUPERSTRONGPASSWORD'
GO
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According my experience, the master key has already created and exist when we create the Azure SQL database.

When we [create master key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-scoped-credential-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#examples) :

```
-- Create a db master key if one does not already exist, using your own password.
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD='<EnterStrongPasswordHere>';
```

Since the master key is already exist, we could not create a new one.

For most situations, Azure SQL database cross db queries don't need create the master key.

For example, I use the bellow query to  do cross db query from Mydatabase to Mydatabase2:

```
--The "username" and "password" should be the username and password used to log in into the Customers database.
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL ElasticDBQueryCred
 WITH IDENTITY = '<username>',
 SECRET = '<password>';  

 --To create an external data source, execute the following command on the Orders database:
 CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyElasticDBQueryDataSrc WITH
    (TYPE = RDBMS,
    LOCATION = '<server_name>.database.windows.net',
    DATABASE_NAME = 'Customers',
    CREDENTIAL = ElasticDBQueryCred,
) ;

--Create an external table on the Orders database, which matches the definition of the CustomerInformation table:
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[test]
( [id] [int] ,
  [age] [int]
  )
WITH
( DATA_SOURCE = MyElasticDBQueryDataSrc)

--query the table 
select * from test
```

Test table in Mydatabase2:
[image]

Cross db query in Mydatabase:
[image]

For details, please reference: [Get started with cross-database queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-getting-started-vertical#database-scoped-master-key-and-credentials).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Leon, thanks for your answer. The point was, to not create a key because there is one already. Second, the External Table should be named as the table in the other database. Now it works great!