# Issue creating master key for Azure SQL Pool - Permission error

Tags: sql-server, azure, encryption, permissions, azure-synapse

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/create-a-database-master-key?view=sql-server-ver16) but I'm having issues with granting CONTROL permission.

This is on a Dedicated SQL pool (formerly SQL DW) within Azure by following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/create-data-warehouse-portal).

I initially try `CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '23987hxJ#KL95234nl0zBe';` which returns

> User does not have permission to perform this action.

So I try to apply CONTROL permission to the user account:
`GRANT CONTROL ON DATABASE::master TO useradmin`

But this returns

> Principal doesn't exist or doesn't have sufficient privileges.

I have search the web for a solution but I cant find one that has yet worked so any help or advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To create MASTER key in azure SQL, follow below statement in Azure SQL data base.

```
CREATE MASTER KEY 
 GO
```

For more details refer this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50459793/cannot-create-master-key-for-master-database-in-azure-sql) by Alberto Morillo and also refer this [Microsoft official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/load-data-from-azure-blob-storage-using-copy#create-external-tables-for-the-sample-data).

**Updated:**

I reproduced same thing in my environment its working fine .

**sample code:**

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD='xxxx'
GO
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL [cred-name] WITH IDENTITY = 'User_name' , SECRET = 'xxxx'
GO
```

[image: Ref1]

Comment: Same error when I try this: `User does not have permission to perform this action.`